# Gedit: replacing some regex-matched text with the same literal regex

Tags: regex, replace, gedit

In gedit 3.28.1 on Ubuntu 18.10, I'm trying to replace some recurring text using a regular expression with the same literal regex. For instance, in the following 2 lines, I need to replace all characters up to the `]` with the replacement regex:

**Find Regex**:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel:( \[ *[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\])?
```

**Replace with literal Regex**:

```
^\\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel:( \\[ *[[:digit:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]+\\])?
```

For instance, if we start with the following "Source text", the goal is to obtain the following "Replaced text"

**Source text**:

```
Aug  1 09:33:49 samsung4-ubuntu kernel: [    0.045109] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
Aug  1 09:33:50 samsung4-ubuntu kernel: [    0.172476] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
```

**Replaced text**:

```
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel:( \[ *[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\])? pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11} [._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel:( \[ *[[:digit:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+\])? Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
```

No replacement is made by gedit.
Has anyone some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try regex: `^\w{3} [ :[:digit:]]{11}[._[:alnum:]-]+ kernel:( [ *[[:digit:]]+.[[:digit:]]+])?`

there was an additional space after `{11}` in your regex.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cSVc82/1)

Comment: My regex is correct: stackoverflow removes what they consider extra blanks; in the original text, there are 2 blanks between Aug and 1. Anyway, this is not the point: I cannot replace the original matched text with the literal regex itself.

Comment: does it work when the replace text is a regular string say `test`?

Comment: yes it does. Another attempt with different regexes: "^[a-zA-Z]{3} [ :0-9]{11} [._a-zA-Z0-9-]+ kernel: [ *[0-9]+\.[0-9]+]" as find regex and "\^[a-zA-Z]\{3\} \[ :0-9\]\{11\} \[._a-zA-Z0-9-\]\+ kernel: \[ \*\[0-9\]\+\\.\[0-9\]\+\]" as escaped replace with regex leads to the same unsuccessful result